# Unable to login to Azure SQL Database using Azure Data Studio

Tags: azure, macos, azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

I am trying to login to my Azure SQL Database using Azure Data Studio since I am using OSX. However, when I try to connect, I am getting this error.

> **Error** -> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (22): Invalid argument    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketErrorAndThrowException(SocketError
> error, Boolean disconnectOnFailure, String callerName)    at
> System.Net.Sockets.Socket.UpdateStatusAfterSocketOptionErrorAndThrowException(SocketError
> error, String callerName)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.SNITCPHandle.Receive(SNIPacket& packet,
> Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.TdsParserStateObjectManaged.ReadSyncOverAsync(Int32
> timeoutRemaining, UInt32& error)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.ReadSniSyncOverAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParserStateObject.TryReadNetworkPacket()
> at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ConsumePreLoginHandshake(SqlConnectionEncryptOption
> encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean&
> marsCapable, Boolean& fedAuthRequired, Boolean tlsFirst, String
> serverCert)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo,
> SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout,
> Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean
> withFailover)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
> serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
> withFailover)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
> serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
> SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
> timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
> Boolean redirectedUserInstance)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
> identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
> credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
> newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
> userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean
> applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool
> pool)    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
> options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
> DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
> DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
> owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions
> userOptions)    at
> Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.<>c__DisplayClass48_0.b__0(Task`1 _)    at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task&
> currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ReliableConnection.ReliableSqlConnection.<>c__DisplayClass30_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> in
> /*/src/Microsoft.SqlTools.ManagedBatchParser/ReliableConnection/ReliableSqlConnection.cs:line
> 313
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer.Connection.ConnectionService.TryOpenConnection(ConnectionInfo
> connectionInfo, ConnectParams connectionParams) in
> /*/src/Microsoft.SqlTools.ServiceLayer/Connection/ConnectionService.cs:line
> 711

I have already set the server-level IP and client IP within the firewall rules. Yet, this error doesn't seem to go away.

My server name is also correctly added as well as my SQL authentication details. I am using MacOS Ventura 13.5.2.

How do I fix this connectivity issue.

Comment: Could you please provide your approach that how you are connecting to Azure SQL database?

Comment: Have you tried to connect using another tool like SSMS, Power BI Desktop, Excel?

Answer (score 0):

When I attempted to connect to the Azure SQL server in Azure Data Studio, I encountered a similar error. The issue occurred because I set the "Trusted certificate" option to "false" while connecting to the SQL server in Data Studio. To resolve this, I changed the `Trusted certificate` option to `true`, as shown below:

[image]

After making this change, the connection was successful, as shown below:

[image]

Ensure that you follow the above procedure, and also try connecting to the SQL server using other tools like SSMS.